# Add numpy array as variable to Xarray Dataset

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

This seems like a very basic operation, but I can't figure out how to do it using the xarray documentation.

I have an xarray DataSet:

```
dss
<xarray.DataArray (y: 1000, x: 1334)>
dask.array<shape=(1000, 1334), dtype=uint8, chunksize=(222, 58)>
Coordinates:
    band     int32 1
  * y        (y) float64 2.218e+06 2.218e+06 2.218e+06 2.218e+06 2.218e+06 ...
  * x        (x) float64 1.891e+06 1.891e+06 1.891e+06 1.891e+06 1.891e+06 ...
Attributes:
    transform:   (30.0, 0.0, -2493045.0, 0.0, -30.0, 3310005.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    crs:         +ellps=GRS80 +lat_0=23 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lon_0=-96 +n...
    res:         (30.0, 30.0)
    is_tiled:    1
    nodatavals:  (nan,)
```

and a numpy array with the correct dimensions:

```
print(np.shape(nmap))
(1000, 1334)
nmap
array([[ 0.15,  0.1 ,  0.15, ...,  0.05,  0.05,  0.02],
       [ 0.15,  0.1 ,  0.05, ...,  0.05,  0.05,  0.05],
       [ 0.1 ,  0.15,  0.15, ...,  0.05,  0.05,  0.02],
       ..., 
       [ 0.02,  0.02,  0.02, ...,  0.02,  0.02,  0.02],
       [ 0.02,  0.09,  0.09, ...,  0.02,  0.02,  0.02],
       [ 0.02,  0.09,  0.09, ...,  0.02,  0.02,  0.02]])
```

I would like to add the array to the DataSet. My ultimate goal is to do spatial interpolation using `x` and `y` to extract interpolated values of `nmap` on a new grid.

Comment: The answer by @keisuke-fujii helped me recognize the difference between a Dataset and a DataArray. Now I will re-ask the question with a real Dataset dsc. Why does this not work?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-3ac64cebb960> in <module>()
      3 #dsc2
      4 # add the Manning's n array
----> 5 dsc2['n']=(('eta_rho','xi_rho'),cnmapi)

TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 16):

Do you want to create a Dataset that contains your numpy array nmap?
Or do you want to make an arithmetic `dss + nmap`?

For the former case,
you need to make a `Dataset` from `dss` first and assign `nmap` to it,
as your `dss` is not a `Dataset` but a `DataArray`.

To make a `Dataset` from `DataArray`s, you can pass a dictionary mapping the array name to the DataArray object.
If your array is not a `DataArray` but a numpy array or dask array, you need a tuple (dimensions, array, [attribute]).

```
ds = xr.Dataset({'dss': dss, 'nmap': (('y', 'x'), nmap)})
```

Or another way to do the same thing is

```
ds = xr.Dataset({})
ds['dss'] = ds
ds['nmap'] = (('y', 'x'), nmap)
```

For the latter case, simply do

```
dss + nmap
```

Comment: ds['nmap'] = (('y', 'x'), nmap) this is what I was searching for. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Suppose you want to add temperature data to a data set:

```
# Take the following dataset as an example
data_set=xr.Dataset( coords={'lon': (['x', 'y'], lon),
                    'lat': (['x', 'y'], lat),
                    'time': pd.date_range('2014-09-06', periods=3)})
temp=np.array([[25, 24, 20, -12],[23, 21, 22, -11]])
data_set["Temperature"]=(['x', 'y', 'time'],  temp)
```

Comment: +1 for the this answer: I tried first supplying a `dict` of the dimension names (e.g. ```{'x','y','time'}``` but it failed. I had to give it the list in square brackets.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way would be by using the [`assign`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.assign.html) method, example:

```
ds = ds.assign(variable_name=(['dim1','dim2'],your_array))
```

You have to remember that you cannot set a new variable with 2-dimensional data (or more) without explicit dimension names. That's why you need to pass a tuple of (dims, data) instead.