# Python, adding a Water-Year time variable in an X-array

Tags: datetime, python-xarray, assign, resampling

I have the following Xarray named 'scatch' with lat long and lev coords eliminated and only the time coord as a dimension. It has several variables. It is now a multivariate daily time-series from 2002 to 2014. I need to add a new variable "water_year", that shows what water-year is that day of the year. It could be by adding another column in the variables by Xarray.assign or by Xarray.resample but I am not sure, and could use some help. Note: "Water Year" starts from Oct 01, and ends on Sep 30 the next year. So water-year-2003 would be 10-01-2002 to 09-30-2003.

See my Xarray here

[image: See my Xarray here]

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51196438/10197418)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll create a sample dataset with a single variable for this example:

```py
In [2]: scratch = xr.Dataset(
   ...:     {'Baseflow': (('time', ), np.random.random(4018))},
   ...:     coords={'time': pd.date_range('2002-10-01', freq='D', periods=4018)},
   ...: )

In [3]: scratch
Out[3]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:   (time: 4018)
Coordinates:
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-10-01 2002-10-02 ... 2013-09-30
Data variables:
    Baseflow  (time) float64 0.7588 0.05129 0.9914 ... 0.7744 0.6581 0.8686
```

We can build a `water_year` array using the [`Datetime Components`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/time-series.html#datetime-components) accessor [`.dt`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.accessor_dt.DatetimeAccessor.html):

```py
In [4]: water_year = (scratch.time.dt.month >= 10) + scratch.time.dt.year
   ...: water_year
Out[4]:
<xarray.DataArray (time: 4018)>
array([2003, 2003, 2003, ..., 2013, 2013, 2013])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-10-01 2002-10-02 ... 2013-09-30
```

Because water_year is a DataArray indexed by an existing dimension, we can just add it as a coordinate and xarray will understand that it's a [non-dimension coordinate](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/user-guide/data-structures.html#coordinates). This is important to make sure we don't create a new dimension in our data.

```py
In [7]: scratch.coords['water_year'] = water_year

In [8]: scratch
Out[8]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (time: 4018)
Coordinates:
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-10-01 2002-10-02 ... 2013-09-30
    water_year  (time) int64 2003 2003 2003 2003 2003 ... 2013 2013 2013 2013
Data variables:
    Baseflow    (time) float64 0.7588 0.05129 0.9914 ... 0.7744 0.6581 0.8686
```

Because `water_year` is indexed by `time`, we still need to select from the arrays using the `time` dimension, but we can subset the arrays to specific water years:

```py
In [9]: scratch.sel(time=(scratch.water_year == 2010))
Out[9]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (time: 365)
Coordinates:
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 2009-10-01 2009-10-02 ... 2010-09-30
    water_year  (time) int64 2010 2010 2010 2010 2010 ... 2010 2010 2010 2010
Data variables:
    Baseflow    (time) float64 0.441 0.7586 0.01377 ... 0.2656 0.1054 0.6964
```

Aggregation operations can use non-dimension coordinates directly, so the following works:

```py
In [10]: scratch.groupby('water_year').sum()
Out[10]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (water_year: 11)
Coordinates:
  * water_year  (water_year) int64 2003 2004 2005 2006 ... 2010 2011 2012 2013
Data variables:
    Baseflow    (water_year) float64 187.6 186.4 184.7 ... 185.2 189.6 192.7
```

Comment: Excellent Michael, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for the effort explaining this.